# How to achieve this specific metalic look in Photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, tutorial

Using photoshop, [how do I get an image to have this silvery/metallic look](http://www.flickr.com/photos/joshuacraig/2351735931/in/photostream/)?

I know how the scene was lit--the photographer explains how, so I am aware how to duplicate that part of it, but I believe the final image had post-processing to achieve the silvery/metallic look.

Once the image is properly lit, how do you finish the image to get a similar result?

Edited to Add:

If you look at the photographers other work using this setup, it seems pretty clear that it wasn't all done with just lighting. For example: http://www.flickr.com/photos/joshuacraig/2362070167/in/photostream/.

Comment: Are you sure there is any special post-processing to achieve that? It looks like very basic processing to me...perhaps just a bit of desaturation. I think the lighting setup takes care of the rest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Other things to try:

- leave mids and highlights neutral-to-warm, cold tone only the shadows
- selective sharpening (**Edit** with the [new example](http://www.flickr.com/photos/joshuacraig/2362070167/sizes/o/in/photostream/), I'm pretty sure on this one. Though whether it's a fundamental aspect, I couldn't really say. Could probably work globally just as well.)
- slight overexposure
- [Local Contrast Enhancement](http://www.luminous-landscape.com/tutorials/contrast-enhancement.shtml), or its sibling, [Adobe's "Clarity" tool](http://photoshopnews.com/2007/05/31/about-camera-raw-41/).
- on the outside, perhaps some mild tone mapping? Seems like overkill in this situation, though.  (Well, to me it *always* seems like overkill, but you know what I mean)

I think the lighting *and the subject* is the fundamental part of the look.  Glossy dark fur would catch highlights, then some processing to enhance that contrast.

Comment: Its also got a lot of vignetting.

Comment: @Alex: The vignetting is from the background lights.

Comment: I think the primary components of the look are lighting and local contrast enhancement.

Comment: @Alan Not in your new example, is isn't!  The dog was a bit ambiguous in this regard, but given the new one, I'd have to lean towards enhancement.

Comment: @Henry likewise. Selective blur/sharpening just for the same reasons one always would (draw attention).

Answer (score 5):

I think you can do this by toning the image towards cold tones (in GIMP it's Colors/Color Balance: you tone down reds and enhance blues, Photoshop should be similar) and then decreasing saturation (Hue/saturation adjustment should be somewhere there as well).

Answer (score 1):

- B800 through white umbrella on right and left.
- BR800 on camera
- B1600 with 20 degree grid on backdrop

An umbrella flash unit on each side with a ringflash on the camera.

There's a shot of the setup [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/joshuacraig/2352605637/).

Comment: I read how he did the lighting. I'm asking how to do the post-processing.

Answer (score 1):

That is no special effect.

It's just a slightly over-sharpened high contrast black-and-white picture. Then the flickr software has added more sharpening when resizing the image to make it really over-sharpened.

Comment: I think its just desaturated, as you can still see some pink in the puppies skin around his nose. I generally agree though, just over-sharpened and desaturated, not much in the way of processing.

Comment: If you look at his other work for example: http://www.flickr.com/photos/joshuacraig/2362070167/in/photostream/, this is not just all lighting based.

Comment: @Alan: Same there, very high contrast and slightly oversharpened. Very easy to repeat if you want it.